# Writing C++ tests with "faking" some methods with an alternative implementation

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm writing tests in C++ using googleTest and want to improve them.

I try to describe what I have and what I want to achieve:

I have a class A that has an instance of class B as a member like this:

```
class ClassA
{
   public:
      //Some functions
   protected:
      ClassB m_b;
};
class ClassB
{
   void Init(const string &sArgument);
};
```

In my test I create an instance of ClassA and call a function of it. In this function the function Init() of m_b will be called.

Because Init() of ClassB makes something that I don't want to have in my test I want to call an alternate implementation. My first intention was to create an interface with the function Init() that is implemented by ClassB and by a new class that I create only for the test. Unfortunately to do this I have to create a pointer of the interface and to give it to ClassA.

```
__interface IB
{
   void Init(const string &sArgument);
};

class ClassB : public IB
{
   void Init(const string &sArgument) override;
};
   
class ClassA
{
   public:
      ClassA(IB* b) : m_b(b){}
     //Some functions
   protected:
      *IB m_b;
 };
```

For my test I create a new class:

```
class ClassBForTest : public IB
{
   void Init(const string &sArgument) override;
};
```

This is not a good solution so I tried to find another way. What I actually found is the library Isolator++ by Typemock which works quite good. I can say that for all future instances of ClassB the method Init should be replaced with another one. And the best is that I don't have to make any changes in my ClassA. I just have to create a new one:

```
class ClassBForTest
{
  void ISOLATOR_TESTABLE Init(const string &sArgument){}
};
```

In my test I use this:

```
ClassBForTest c;
ClassB* b = FAKE_ALL<ClassB>();
WHEN_CALLED(b->Init(ANY_VAL(string))).DoMemberFunctionInstead(&c, Init);
```

Unfortunately this library is not for free when I want to use it on a build server. So I'm searching for an alternative. As we used gMock in our other tests I tried to realize this with gmock but it didn't work yet. I know that this is not a good statement but I don't want code from you. I only want to know if this is possible with gMock (saying that an alternate implementation should be used without having the instance of ClassB at this point).

Alternatively I ask you for other free libraries I can use.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Michaela

Comment: if testing code is hard then the code is bad, anyway you could use templates for this, but this won't answer your question.

Comment: It seems that you are approaching the tests wrong. What are you trying to test? You must never assume the details of implementation when you test

Comment: What if you conditionally build your code for testing? I.e. `#ifdef TEST ... #endif` and use specific implementation.

Comment: If `ClassB` is so uncoupled from `ClassA` that you would want to change `ClassB` in tests, it's more than likely you should be passing it in as an argument to the constructor of `ClassA` in any case. This is called dependency injection.

Comment: `Alternatively I ask you for other free libraries I can use.` - unfotunately it is against of SO policy. You can't ask for libraries here

Comment: `This is not a good solution so I tried to find another way.` Why do you think this is not a good solution? In my opinion, this is the way to go.

Comment: The class that I want to test (called ClassA here) communicates with another application by building a pipe and send strings to it. My aim is to test if all my function calls create the correct strings. Because I don't want to use the other application in my test I write the string into a text file instead of sending to pipe. In the end I compare the text file if it contains all I expect.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking for another library. I overlooked that it's not allowed.

Comment: `Why do you think this is not a good solution? In my opinion, this is the way to go.` This is what my boss says so I have to find another solution.

Comment: @vahancho: This is the way we are doing in some other tests but I hope that there will be a better way without having code just for testing in the original class.

Comment: So no one knows if this is possible with gMock? In this case I use one of the other solutions.